# How to edit file system of partition?

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-14.04

```
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/home/milenko# parted -l
Model: ATA FUJITSU MHZ2250B (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  248GB  248GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      248GB   250GB  2140MB  extended
 5      248GB   250GB  2140MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Number 2 is extended type.What should I do to create file system ext4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ext4 file system on partition #1. And you do not need to change #2 to ext4 until you do not know exactly what are you doing.
Partition #3 is the logical partition inside the extended partition #2. It's Linux swap partition.
Use fdisk utility to manage partitions and mkfs to build file systems.

Comment: Actually problems occured when I tried to mount iso image to /mnt/iso. mount: you must specify the filesystem type. How to select the wright partition?

Comment: If you need to mount iso image file, use `mount -o loop file.iso /mnt/iso` where file.iso is your iso file name and  /mnt/iso is the destination directory for mounting.

Comment: I have tried it,but I got:mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/home/milenko/2014a# fsck /dev/sda -f
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sda is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: There is no any direct relation between /dev/sda and your iso file. Are you sure that the iso file is not damaged? Try to mount any other iso file.